# Git revert last commit in heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I made acommit and pushed it to origin and heroku

Then I realised it was wrong, so I did

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

But when I'm pushing to Heroku Im getting

```
To git@heroku.com:app.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:app.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I understand the problem. How should I proceed? How can I revert also last heroku commit? (I assume would be the best solution)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you've reverted the commit locally you may need to `git push` with a `-f` option to force the commit in.

Also, you may want to have a look at [Heroku releases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases) which may help too.

Comment: `heroku releases` is priceless, exactly what I needed. Also shows `heroku rollback`, very helpful!

Comment: `heroku releases` is cool, but rolling back and trying to push didn't work for me. Instead I just pushed with `--force`, and that did the trick.

Comment: `heroku releases` lists the release history and the version numbers. Select a version number you want then do (for instance) `heroku rollback v15`

Answer (score 54):

From http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback

Use the rollback command to roll back to the last release:

```
$ heroku rollback
Rolled back to v51
```

You may choose to specify another release to target:

```
$ heroku rollback v40
Rolled back to v40
```

Comment: That is amazing!! It's exactly how you'd want it to work.
I wish Apple had that for their App Store. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Given that you have already pushed to other (public?) repositories, the best way to fix this is probably to undo the `git reset` locally, then do a `git revert` to create a new commit that reverses the effects of the bad commit.  Then push everything again.  So step by step:

1. So first `git reset --hard origin/master` or `git reset --hard heroku/master` (or whatever your heroku tracking branch is called), in order to get your local `master` back the bad commit.  This will blow away any outstanding changes in your working copy, so be careful.
2. Then `git revert HEAD` to create a new commit (it will prompt you for a commit message).
3. Then push as you usually would.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. First, I created a new branch with the old commit:

```
git checkout -b old-rev <commit-id>
```

Then I ran `push -f` the old branch on the local repo to heroku's master:

```
git push -f heroku old-rev:master
```

When I'm done with the old version and ready to get to the new version:

```
git checkout master
git push heroku master
git branch -d old-rev  # deletes the old branch; warns if there will be data loss
```